# Dropbox Thumbnails

Tags: c#, dropbox, sharpbox

I am Using SharpBox Api for accessing Dropbox, but retrieving thumbnails is not supported.

Is there any way in a .NET api for Dropbox to get thumbnails?

Answer (score 1):

The Core API is documented here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs, and this is the thumbnails endpoint: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#thumbnails.

I don't know whether SharpBox supports calling that endpoint, but you should be able to do it yourself pretty easily if you have an OAuth token for the user.

Comment: i changed my api ... i am using Dropnet now , its implemented in dropnet, btw thanks